# Different product card components are going to be passed dynamically to a carousel how do I pass props to a component received through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**ProductCard.js** and **Carousel.js** have been import into **App.js**

**App.js** has **state={}** with myArray an array of object with product card details such as *productName*

now **ProductCard** is passed as a prop to **Carousel** so as *myArray* from the state in **App.js**

`<Carousel element={<ProductCard />} myArray={this.state.myArray} />`

now the **ProductCard** also accepts props such as *productName* from myArray. So how do l iterate the data in *myArray* passing props into **ProductCard** in **Carousel.js**

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Carousel from "./Carousel";
import ProductCard from "./ProductCard";
import ProductCard2 from "./ProductCard2";

class App extends Component{
  state = {
     myArray:[
        { 
          productName: "Red T-shirt"
          id: 1
          imgUrl: 'https://image1.com'
        },{
           productName: "Yellow T-shirt"
          id: 2
          imgUrl: 'https://image2.com'
        },{
           productName: "Blue T-shirt"
          id: 3
          imgUrl: 'https://image3.com'
        }
      ]
   }
   render(){
     return(
        <div>
           <h1>Trending</h1>
           <Carousel element={<ProductCard />} myArray={this.state.myArray} />

           <h1>New Arrivals</h1>
           <Carousel element={<ProductCard2 />} myArray={this.state.myArray} />
        </div>
     )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Carousel**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";


class Carousel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.next = this.next.bind(this);
        this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);
    }
    next() {
        this.slider.slickNext();
    }
    previous() {
        this.slider.slickPrev();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ml-slick-carousel position-relative mx-auto">
                <Slider>

                   Now how do I iterate myArray from Props and passing data from the array into the card.

                </Slider>
                <button  onClick={this.previous}>Prev</button>
                <button onClick={this.next}>Next</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Export default Carousel;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post your js code inline so that we can review.

Comment: i posted sample code